# Which color scheme is better for a logo monochrome or complementary?

Tags: color, logo

I decided to redesign the logo for my [VAT calculator](https://vatulator.com/). It's a progressive web app so it has the ability to display on the home screen of a mobile or PC. So the goal is to make the logo more prominent against other apps.
[image]
On the left is a new version of the logo with a complimentary color scheme. On the right is the old logo with a monochrome color scheme.

Which logo stands out better? Is the new logo appropriate for the current app design?

Comment: I cant get past the poor kerning ....

Comment: Hmm... I know that you may not care but that name would essentially mean something like a procrastinator or a system that would never get anything done in Finnish ;)

Comment: Personally, I can't see anything wrong with either colour scheme. Neither is "better" than the other. Colour choice is highly subjective. Go with what you like! However you do need to fix the kerning of the text underneath. It's quite distracting.

Comment: Opinions:  The red draws attention from the name which should be considered important. The green-black looks pro except the A letters have far too much space around them. Try this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TytKJ.png  At least Indesign would set it right automatically if you have a pro quality font. Vatulate can be seen as a verb. User joojaa has already has said it

Comment: @user287001 Thanks, I'll try to fix the kerning

Comment: @joojaa In fact, when I came up with the name I combined two words VAT and calculator))

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherently better color combination for logos, it very much depends on what you're trying to say, which colors, target audience, etc. And complementary/monochrome are not your only options.

In this particular case, the left color combination says very much stop/go to me. Red=negative, green=positive. Looking at your app design, I get that this reflects your add/subtract functionality, but I'm not quite sure this would be obvious to someone looking at just the logo.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. If we look at the CTR of a logo, for example, when using it as a favicon. Which logo is preferable? It seems to me that a complimentary color scheme is more eye-catching.